# Software Foundations: weak_pumping lemma proof

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

Continuing my work on Software Foundations, I've reached the `weak_pumping` lemma. I managed to get through almost everything, but I can't find a solution for `MStarApp` case.

Here's the Lemma:

```
  s =~ re ->
  pumping_constant re <= length s ->
  exists s1 s2 s3,
    s = s1 ++ s2 ++ s3 /\
    s2 <> [] /\
    forall m, s1 ++ napp m s2 ++ s3 =~ re.

(** You are to fill in the proof. Several of the lemmas about
    [le] that were in an optional exercise earlier in this chapter
    may be useful. *)
Proof.
  intros T re s Hmatch.
  induction Hmatch
    as [ | x | s1 re1 s2 re2 Hmatch1 IH1 Hmatch2 IH2
       | s1 re1 re2 Hmatch IH | re1 s2 re2 Hmatch IH
       | re | s1 s2 re Hmatch1 IH1 Hmatch2 IH2 ].
```

I've managed to solve every case, except for the last one. Here's the current state:

```
1 subgoal (ID 918)
  
  T : Type
  s1, s2 : list T
  re : reg_exp T
  Hmatch1 : s1 =~ re
  Hmatch2 : s2 =~ Star re
  IH1 : pumping_constant re <= length s1 ->
        exists s2 s3 s4 : list T,
          s1 = s2 ++ s3 ++ s4 /\
          s3 <> [ ] /\ (forall m : nat, s2 ++ napp m s3 ++ s4 =~ re)
  IH2 : pumping_constant (Star re) <= length s2 ->
        exists s1 s3 s4 : list T,
          s2 = s1 ++ s3 ++ s4 /\
          s3 <> [ ] /\ (forall m : nat, s1 ++ napp m s3 ++ s4 =~ Star re)
  H : pumping_constant (Star re) <= length s1 + length s2
  ============================
  exists s0 s4 s5 : list T,
    s1 ++ s2 = s0 ++ s4 ++ s5 /\
    s4 <> [ ] /\ (forall m : nat, s0 ++ napp m s4 ++ s5 =~ Star re)
```

It looks to me that if I can find a way to split `H` into `pumping_constant re <= length s1 \/ pumping_constant (Star re) <= length s2` then I have a way forward (by splitting `H` into `H1` and `H2` and applying the relevant `IHk` to the matching `Hk` then proceeding with a `destruct`, three `exists`, and so on).

But I can't find a lemma that allows me to split `H` as suggested.

Is there anything else I can do here?

Thanks

Comment: I haven't thought about your specific problem, but note that it is not true in general that `a <= b + c` implies `a <= b \/ a <= c`. For example, `3 <= 2 + 1`. Either there is some fact about your specific case that you can use to reach that conclusion, or you need to think of a different strategy. Try to prove the result with pen and paper if your problem is being unsure about the direction of the proof and not how to implement a proof you already know will work.

Comment: What is pumping constant for Star? Isn't it zero?

Comment: unfortunately not, pumping_constant for any RE is at least 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to destruct s1 and look again on lemma napp_star in one of cases.

Comment: this helped a little, still missing some detail. Thanks :-)

Comment: Try to see that in zero-case you can use IH. And in non-zero case you need napp_star. Or you can try to describe what is your question now.

Comment: Right, Andrey. I can see that I need that. The problem I have now is that I can't apply napp_star because I don't have hypothesis for the current lists. I'll try to explain a little better. I have these hypothesis in context:   Hmatch1 : x :: s1' =~ re, Hmatch2 : [ ] =~ Star re, but the goal is: s2'' ++ napp m s3'' ++ s4'' =~ Star re. When I try napp_star, I get the expected "unable to unify" error.

Comment: Perhaps my "exists" are incorrect :-) I'll keep trying :-)

Comment: It looks to me like you have destructed s2 also. becuase you have `[] ~= Star re`. it works for me if I destruct s1 only.

Comment: Tried that. I always get stuck. Guess I need to take a break from this exercise :-s

  - (* MStarApp *)
    intros. destruct s1 as [| x s1'] eqn:Es1.
    + simpl. apply IH2 in H. apply H.
    + simpl.

Comment: I think if you will take a break, you will most likely solve it then. You are very close. But I suppose you need to look at the essense of question to write correct exist.

Comment: I did it. Thank you so much @Andrey. Couldn't have done it without your comments :-)

Comment: Great, congratulations :)